# How run flutter app on 64 bit devices(android)?

Tags: android, flutter, 64-bit

I created flutter app. But my app not run on 64  bit android devices. I need apk file(not app bundle).

I tried this solution:

1. add abiFilters ([this article](https://medium.com/flutterpub/flutter-app-couldnt-find-libflutter-so-c95ad81cbccd)):

   ```
   ndk {
   abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'
   }
   ```

This worked for me, but now again the problem. perhaps this is due to the latest update.

2. buid apk this command(abiFilters  is comment)

   ```
   flutter build apk --split-per-abi
   ```

   I have app-arm64-v8a-release.apk, but this apk is not work. app freezes on splash screen.

Any advices?

Comment: did you put abiFilters in release?

Comment: yes, I added this in release

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. I run this command for build:

```
 flutter build apk --release --target-platform=android-arm64
```

i found it [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18494#issuecomment-477502287)